# c++ this, *this, &instance in operator= function confused me so much

Tags: c++

In c++'s operator= function I read a lot like this:

```
ClassA & ClassA::operator=(const ClassA & instance){
    if(this == &instance){
        return *this;
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

"this" is a pointer that points to current ClassA's instance, and "*this" is current instance's address. But why (this == &instance) ?  "&instance" is another ClassA instance's address, "this" is only a pointer. why should (this==&instance)??? 
Confused me so much, thanks ahead for any help. And also, instance is the same thing with instance address?

Comment: Imagine `a = a;`, but better yet, use the copy-swap idiom.

Comment: You're wrong about `*this` - that is not an address, but the actual object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have an instance of class A, say x

```
A x;

//Equal operation

x = x;
```

In this case you just want to assign the same object to itself again, So you don't need to do all the copying for the attributes of the object, to avoid these unwanted assignment operations, there is always used to be an if condition at the very start to check whether you are assigning the same object to itself, there you just need to check whether the addresses are same.

```
   `(this == &instance)`
```

here `this` is pointing to x now (i.e holding the address of the object instance x) and when you do the assignment operation (`x=x`), instance is the x object and &instance is address of the x object and `this` also hold the address of the x, so the if condition evaluates to true and what you want to do is just assign the same address again to &x (no need of deep copying of the attributes of the object)

Answer (score 1):

The test `this == &instance` tests for *self-assignment*, i.e. the case where the operand is the object itself:

```
Foo x;
x = x;   // or: x.operator=(x)
```

The "problem" is that C++ has very poor aliasing control, and you can't know, or restrict, whether any two pointers or references denote the same object. So you have to test.

For something simple ans integers, self assignment wouldn't be a huge deal, but imagine a basic, naive "smart pointer" (it wouldn't be very smart, though):

```
 struct TPtr
 {
     T * ptr;
     TPtr(T * p) : ptr(p) {}
     TPtr(TPtr const & rhs)  : ptr(new T(*rhs.ptr)) {}
     ~TPtr() { delete ptr; }

     TPtr & operator=(TPtr const & rhs)
     {
         delete ptr;
         ptr = new T(*rhs.ptr);   // uh-oh
     }
 };
```

Can you spot the problem?

Comment: I know there is problem with "delete ptr", but why shouldn't delete self(or say this)?

Comment: @user1193710: Think about it: What is `rhs.ptr`? Is it safe to say `*rhs.ptr` when `rhs` is the same object as `*this`?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, 'this' is a pointer. And the pointer is the address! So pointer and address is the same and I will use these terms in the same meaning below. 
I guess you are a bit confused with & and * as they mean different things when applied to the type and to the variable.

```
ClassA & refVar; //this way you declare a reference
ClassA* pVar;  //this way you declare a pointer
refvar; //this is a reference
pVar; // this is a pointer

//To get pointer from the reference you need to get an address.
&refVar; //this is a pointer (an address)

// To get a reference from pointer you need to derefecence it
*pVar; // this is a reference!
```

So now it should be clear why 'instance' is a reference and 'this' is a pointer (address) in your example. To verify if it is the same object we need to get address of the reference 'instance' and compare it to the pointer 'this'. That is why the correct comparison is

```
if(this == &instance) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know clearly what a pointer is. A pointer contains address of the data type being pointed.

In this case, the "this" pointer points to the object instantiated from ClassA, which means "this" equals to the address of the object.Having a pointer, you use an asterisk(*) in front of a pointer to access the object being pointed to.

Thus, "*this" IS the current instance, not its address.

(this == &instance) is a comparison of equalness between a pointer(which is the address of current instance) and address of "instance".

This is to check if the parameter passed(by reference) into the function is the current instance itself. This extra check can avoid some unwanted situation/exception.

Instance is not the same thing as instance address.

```
ClassA myObject; //myObject is an instance
ClassA * ptr;    //ptr is a pointer that only points to objects of ClassA 
ptr = &myObject; //&myObject is instance address, assign address of myObject to ptr
                 //in other words, make ptr point to myObject
(*ptr).someFunction(); //use asterisk to access object members
```